# Do independent variables need to be normally distributed in negative binomial regression?

Tags: regression, normality-assumption, negative-binomial-distribution

From searching around, I see that independent variables in logistic and linear regression do not need to be normally distributed, but I haven't found any information about negative binomial regression.

**Is there any need for independent variables to be normally distributed in negative binomial regressions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**

This is a common misconception about generalized linear models. I think people see that the error term in an OLS linear regression is supposed to be normal (for the usual inferences to work) and take that to mean either the pooled distribution of all $y$ values must be normal or that the features must be normal, both of which are false.

In particular, binary $0/1$ variables are perfectly okay in generalized linear models (such as a GLM with a negative binomial likelihood).

Comment: Just to expand on this answer (since the OP wasn't phrased in terms of GLMs): binary independent variables are also ok in multinomial logit, ordered logit, poisson, tobit, and basically any other kind of model you can think of. In general the "rules" for how to treat independent variables (such as the creation of interaction terms, creating dummy variables for nominal categorical variables, adding quadratic terms, etc) don't depend on what type of model you are running. Of course the interpretation of the resulting coefficient WILL depend on the type of model you ran.